# "Gave up waiting for root device," boot-repair failed

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04, boot-repair

I had Fedora 20 installed on my laptop, then I recently did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 on the machine. Finished the install, and restarted the machine to get this screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhWw5.jpg I have used Ubuntu on this machine sucessfully in previous installations.

I ran boot-repair and it said it successfully repaired GRUB. So I restarted the machine and got the same screen from above. Here are the pastebin results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7463525/

Can you please help? I'm at a complete loss. It seems GRUB is possibly corrupted, but I'm also getting about error about "/dev/disk/by-uuid/.... does not exist."

Comment: Boot from live disk and show the output of the command `blkid`. Then make sure that the entry in `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` matches the UUID of the partition where `/` is to be mounted. If that doesn't help, run `boot-repair` again

Comment: Interestingly enough, I decided to dual boot Ubuntu alongside the existing Ubuntu installation... The new Ubuntu partition boots just fine. Can I delete the 'broken' partition of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't have a lot of important data on this machine, I decided on an experiment - I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 next to the original install of Ubuntu. Then using Gparted I deleted the original (corrupt) installation of Ubuntu. This 'magically' fixed it. Not really a solution but it's how I solved it.